# make a Tab Dependent Selection List? Angular 7 Materials

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 7 with angular materials.

I have a tab and a selection list and I would like that the values that appear in the selection list to depend on the selection on the tab-group.

Not sure what is the best way to make this happen, I was thinking a function that literally creates  a new list, receiving as parameter the 2 lists and the property in common , in the data.

My tab-group is filled pretty much with letters
and then I would add the letter as a property on the list objects.

Is there a better way to do this?

my code is looking like this:
(html)

```
 <mat-tab class="error-label mat-tab-labels-errors" *ngFor="let areaItem of areaList, let i = index"
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let err of errors" [value]="err.id">
```

(ts)

```
areaList: string[] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'L', 'T'];
  errors = [
    { id: 'A7', clientName: 'fd', type: 'A' },
    { id: 'B1', clientName: 'sdfdfsu', type: 'B' },
    { id: 'E3', clientName: 'sdf', type: 'C' },
    { id: 'I2', clientName: 'fsdfu', type: 'D' },
    { id: 'L', clientName: 'sdfsf', type: 'L' },
    { id: 'L', clientName: 'sdfsf', type: 'T' }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="change($event.value)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let list of errors" [value]="list.type">
    {{list.type}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value"
               (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of areaList; let index = index" [label]="tab">
    Contents for {{tab}} tab
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

 areaList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'L', 'T'];
  selected = new FormControl(0);
  errors = [
    { id: 'A7', clientName: 'fd', type: 'A' },
    { id: 'B1', clientName: 'sdfdfsu', type: 'B' },
    { id: 'E3', clientName: 'sdf', type: 'C' },
    { id: 'I2', clientName: 'fsdfu', type: 'D' },
    { id: 'L', clientName: 'sdfsf', type: 'L' },
    { id: 'L', clientName: 'sdfsf', type: 'T' }
  ];
change(event)
  {
      console.log(event);
      this.selected = new FormControl(this.areaList.indexOf(event));    
  }
```